# Why does the initial execution of my CUDA program take longer than subsequent executions?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I have test.cu file and it's compiling with NVCC

```
void sort()
{

thrust::host_vector<int> dat1(50);
thrust::generate(dat1.begin(),dat1.end(),rand);

for(int i=0; i<dat1.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << dat1[i] << std::endl;
}

thrust::device_vector<int> dev_vec1 = dat1;


thrust::sort(dev_vec1.begin(),dev_vec1.end());
thrust::copy(dev_vec1.begin(),dev_vec1.end(),dat1.begin());

for(int i=0; i<dat1.size(); i++)
{
    std::cout << dat1[i] << std::endl;
}

}


#include "test.cuh"


int main()
{
   sort();
   return 0;
}
```

but sorting on device take 40 sec.. but when I'm run it second time it's working fast.
What's problem?

Comment: One thing that may help on a linux system is to set the GPU in persistence mode.  `nvidia-smi -g 0 -pm 1` , you can get help by `nvidia-smi --help`.    Another contributing factor may be a JIT-compile step, depending on how you are compiling your code.  The first time you launch a new code that does not have the actual binary for the GPU in question, it must do a final compile step to create it.  This will usually only happen once, because it is cached.  You can avoid this by issuing your compile with an appropriate `-arch=sm_xx` switch, where xx is the compute capability of your GPU

Comment: " 
You can avoid this by issuing your compile with an appropriate -arch=sm_xx switch, where xx is the compute capability of your GPU"
 how to do it?

Comment: What kind of GPU do you have, and what is the nvcc compile command line you are using?

Comment: You can get the compute capability of your gpu [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) or by running [the deviceQuery sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#utilities).  Let's say I have a GeForce GTX 560.  Then my compute capability is 2.1  Now let's say my application source file is sort.cu.  To compile this I would issue the command `nvcc -arch=sm_21 -o sort sort.cu`   The `-arch=sm_21` switch tells the compiler to generate code for your specific device.  You can get more help [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#utilities) or with `nvcc --help`

Comment: sorry that was the wrong link, nvcc documentation is [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html).

Comment: The initial lag is almost certainly the time required to JIT.

Comment: I have GTX 570, ok. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason is that during first run your OS is loading CUDA libraries and performing some other technical tasks before actual initialization of CUDA context. At the second run everything is already loaded and context itnitializes faster.

Comment: You can avoid this by issuing your compile with an appropriate -arch=sm_xx switch, where xx is the compute capability of your GPU 

how to do it?